# Need to customize bookmark text instead of standard

Tags: bookmarks, custom

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfencoding=auto,bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,linkcolor=cyan,citecolor=red,urlcolor=green}
\usepackage{bookmark}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}

\chapter{Chapter Title1}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Head Title1}
\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Chapter Title2}
\lipsum[3]

\section{Head Title1}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

And the `bookmark` shown as:

[image]

I need to change in `Bookmark` alone, as `000_001` instead of `Chapter Title1` and `1.1 Head Title1` instead of `Head Title1`, and it should not affect `TOC`

Comment: Use `\texorpdfstring{Actual Chapter/Heading Name}{String to use in Bookmark}`.

Comment: @WillieWong Sorry to ask, can you show just a small `MWE`? Please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\texorpdfstring{<Actual Name>}{<What you want in bookmark>}`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First Part}
\chapter{\texorpdfstring{Chapter Name}{11111}}
\section{\texorpdfstring{Section Name}{1.1.1.1.1}}

\end{document}
```

**Additional Remark**: if you just want the bookmarks corresponding to the chapter/section headings, you don't need to load the `bookmark` package. (The solution above works regardless of whether the `bookmark` package is loaded.)

The `hyperref` package already provides PDF bookmarks; there's no need to use the `bookmark` package unless you want to use the extra features it provides. (This includes: style/color formatting for the bookmarks, and alternative actions [besides "goto page"].) Also, note that the `bookmark` package is highly experimental.

Comment: Much thanks for your kind help ...